# Android broadcast receiver && App running status

Tags: android, broadcast

I used third party push service in my application, when a message is push from server, it's background service will send a broadcast which I have to listen to, this process just works fine. In the function **onReceive()**,I can either show notification or just do some work silently. Whether show notification or not will depend on the app status, that is:

```
if(application_is_running){
    if(message_type == chat_message){
        if(chat_activity_is_present){
            /** notification not allowed **/
        }else{
            /** show notification, open the corresponding chat activity on clicking the notification */
        }
    }else{
        /** store the message silently **/
    }
}else{
    /** show notification, and start the app on clicking the notification**/
}
```

What is the best practice to inform my application when the broadcast receiver gets the push message from server?

--EDIT--

By best practice, I mean the best way to send the message(without changing the message handling logic in my app) to my application to deal with.

Comment: it depends on your requirement. if you want your user to have acknowledgement of push received then you should go with notification And if you want to do any operation that is not important for user to know than it probably goes good silently

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia Yeah, I'm aware of that. But the main problem is that I cannot detect whether my app is up and running or in the background or just get killed by system or crashed. Thus the logic cannot be done in my application. I'll edit my question since I didn't make it clear.

Comment: can you tell which third party push service you are using ?

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia Tencent's Xg push service, you may have never heard of it. I think it's not the problem of push service itself, but how to deal with the broadcast message in my application. Because the broadcast receiver doesn't know when to show notification and when not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help.

1. Use services: it's recommended but I don't like it much.
2. Intents: U could start your application and set flags such as single top which will check if your app is running in the baground and if yes it simply brings it to the app. And if you need to do this silently you could start a separate activity which basically displays a transparent baground and on launch it handles the intent and then closes it self. But of course I services will make the user experience better but I don't have much knowledge in services.

Comment: After one day's research, I agree with this solution, but I need to do some work on learning how to use services. Thanks for help !

Comment: Your welcome and also if you require some help about services. You could use the android developer website just search for "services android developers" and the official guide should be on top